# how to read multiple (loop) .csv files with a date name in R?

Tags: r, loops, date, read.csv

I have several .csv files with these names (from 1 January 2016 to 31 december 2016)

```
    01012016.csv
    02012016.csv
    ...
    31122016.csv
```

I want to use `read.csv(` by using a loop but still considering date patterns.

```
start<-as.Date("01-01-16")
end<-as.Date("31-12-16")
theDate<-start
­{read.csv(theDate,".csv")}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the names of all the files using `list.files` and giving it the path of all folder where all the files are located:

```
filenames = list.files('/path/to/datefiles/', pattern = "*.csv")
```

Then you can use `lapply` to iterate over the vector 'filenames`containing the names of files and apply`read.csv`to each of them and set additional parameters like`header`and`stringsAsFactors` as TRUE or FALSE as required:

```
data = lapply(filenames,read.csv,header = TRUE,stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

Comment: `filenames = list.files('/path/to/files.csv')`
Do I have to write all the dates to replace "files.csv" in the path?

Comment: @user123456 Updated my answer. You can specify the path of the folder where all the csv files are located.

Answer (score 0):

To create a character vector containing the format yyyymmdd you could try:

```
(yyyymmdd.vec <- format(seq(from = as.Date("01-01-16", format = "%d-%m-%y"),
                            to = as.Date("31-12-16", format = "%d-%m-%y"), 
                            by = "day"), format=  "%Y%m%d"))
```