# Using loops or lapply to read and name files

Tags: r, for-loop, import, lapply

I am a beginner to R, so my question may be very basic. I have searched for the answer to this question to the best of my ability, but I could not find what I need.

I have several files containing data collected from each state. I currently have the files titled things such as "ALTable.csv", "DETable.csv", etc.

I want to read these files into a program and save the contents in a named data frame. I then want to go on to perform operations on these data frames, and to use them to construct new data frames filled by computations with the old data frames.

I currently have many lines of code such as

```
AL <- read.csv("ALTable.csv")
DE <- read.csv("DETable.csv")
```

I am trying to avoid having to do this command individually for each state. I was able to find out how to tell R to make a list of the relevant files and how to load them, but I do not know how to tell R to make a list of these files, read them, and saved them as a named data frame.

Similarly, after I have these data frames, I am performing computations with these frames and creating new data frames filled with these computations. I have lines such as

```
MuAL <- AL$prop/AL$pop
MuDE <- DE$prop/DE$pop
```

I would like to perform these computations and save the results with the given names without having to do it for each individual state.

Ideally, I could simply make a single list of all abbreviations and in each line of code where an individual state occurs, insert placeholders where the state abbreviation goes and create a for loop which goes over my list and inserts the abbreviations for the placeholders. However, I have no idea how to do this other than the most naive way, which did not work.

Comment: Your question very broad and this in not a code writing service.  There are multiple questions and answers for reading files with loop and storing them as a data frame like this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46079790/how-to-read-multiple-loop-csv-files-with-a-date-name-in-r.  Once you have the files in a list then please feel free to ask a more specific question.

Comment: @user114263: these two answers might help https://stackoverflow.com/a/48105838/786542 & https://stackoverflow.com/a/48898288/786542

Comment: @Dave2e What more specific question should I ask? I don't know how to be more specific than I was.

Comment: You could possibly use list.files() + map_df() + mutate()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you have a list of your abrevations and all the csv file are indeed named the same way, you could generate a list of dataframe using lapply.

Something like:

```
abbr<- c("AL","DE")
name(abbr)<-abbr
listofDF <- lapply(abbr,function(ab)read.csv(paste0(ab,"Table.csv"))
```

and then you should be able to do `muAL <- listofDF$AL$prop/listofDF$AL$pop` or even if you want to do that for all abbrevation:

```
mu <- lapply(litofDF,function(i)i$prop/i$pop)
```

And here `mu$AL` will store the equivalent of your `MuAL`.

Maybe if you could give some sample of your data that may help to find a good solution.

Answer (score 0):

First put all `.csv` files that you want to load in some folder (let's name folder `data` for this example). Then your's working directory must be set up to the parent directory of this folder. Then you can load all files from this directory as following:

```
for (file in dir('data/')) {
  assign(substr(file, 1, 2), read.csv(paste0('data/', file)))
}
```